# Interview Questions on SharePoint Apps which I could not answer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

Question was :

- Where does the code lies for Provider Hosted App? does it lie in SharePoint server? if not can we make them lie in SharePoint server.
- How should we call the web services for Provider hosted app?
- Can we write JSOM in Provider hosted app?

Anyone can explain in simple language. I am new to SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Where does the code lies for Provider Hosted App? does it lie in
  SharePoint server?

The code for provider hosted app lies in [remote web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx). Remote web    is a web application that is hosted outside sharepoint server. For on    prem installations one needs to set up high trust between sharepoint    and remote web using certificates.

- How should we call the web services for Provider hosted app?

As remote web and sharepoint host site collection lie in different domains you need to use [cross domain library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx) (SP.RequestExecutor) to make cross domain calls to Sharepoint host site collection using REST APIs.

- Can we write JSOM in Provider hosted app?

Yes we can write [JSOM in PHA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx). However you need to load sharepoint client libraries - sp.js and sp.runtime.js

Hope your queries are resolved !!

Comment: Really Good! Keep it up!